# char pointers (strings) compared vs other pointers in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, char

When we create a pointer to int we need to point that pointer to a variable, but when we create a string we only need to point to a word (exemple).
I can't understand why strings can point to values (chars) and other pointers of type int, float can't.

Comment: A string is just a collection of individual characters, so to speak.

Comment: C now has _compound literals_ such as `int *p = (int []){2, 4};` So an example of a pointer to `int`, that does not point to a variable.

Comment: "but when we create a string we only need to point to a word" --> A _string_ is C is not a pointer.  _Strings_ don't point.  It is an _array_ of characters up to an including a terminating null character.  `"Hello"` is a _string literal_ and is also an array 6 of `char`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char* c = {'H','i','\0'};
```

is the same as:

```
char* c = "Hi";
```

sort of like:

```
int* a = {0,1,2,3};
```

is the same as:

```
int* a = malloc(sizeof(int) * 4);
a[0] = 1;
a[1] = 2;
...
...
```

A pointer is a reference to a memory location of the type the pointer was declared to point at, in this case a char.

An array of say 10 chars `char* c[10]`; is 10 continuous memory locations (each the size of 1 char). Here c points to the first location in that continuous memory array. You can randomly access the 10 memory locations using the `[] operator`. `c[0] = 'H'; c[1] = 'i';` or using pointer arithmetic `*c = 'H'; c++; *c = 'i'`;

This may help: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/ntcs/

Answer (score 2):

A pointer of to `int` *can* point to a value that isn't contained in a variable:

```
int* p;
p = malloc(sizeof(int));
*p = 5;
```

The value 5 isn't contained in any variable, but `p` is pointing to it.

Your question really concerns how pointers are *initialized*. There is an element of arbitrariness in the way that string literals can initialize a char pointer and array literals can initialize arrays but int literals can't initialize int pointers. Ultimately, that is just the way the language is. With the way that int pointers are typically used (to either pass variables by reference or in dynamic data structures), there really isn't very many natural use-cases for initializing a single int pointer to point to a literal value when declaring it.

Comment: in that case we are creating an array of 1 element?

Answer (score -1):

In C a string literal is not a scalar value but an array of char